# What are the best alternatives for Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android app and want to know which are the alternatives of google Firebase for storing data, as I want to spend money on purchasing premium plans. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not :)

Also I think your question is constructed a little bit wrong.
If you want to use more storage you can do it with firebase, there are avaialble non-free plans.
If you do not want to spend money you need to use less storage or any other firebase feature or other service feature.